# Solaris 10: Alternative to dirfd()

Tags: c++, c, linux, solaris-10

I had worked on RHEL 6.5 and developed some code which would use the function `dirfd()` for `readdir_r()`, like shown below:

```
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    void some_function(){
            DIR *dir = NULL;
            struct dirent *pentry = NULL, *next_file = NULL;
                if ((dir = opendir("/ZB_RQ/")) != NULL) {
                        len_pentry = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + fpathconf(dirfd(dir), _PC_NAME_MAX) + 1;
                        pentry = malloc(len_pentry);
                        if(!pentry){
                            exit(0);
                        }

                        for(;;){
                            readdir_r(dir, pentry, &next_file);
                            if(!next_file){
                                //No file to iterate.
                                break;
                            }
                            else{
                                // do something
                            }
                        }
                  }
    }
```

This piece of codes work fine in RHEL 6.5 (Linux) but when I run this in `Oracle Solaris 10`, it fails with an error `Undefined symbol dirfd`.

I have searched this fucntion in `/usr/include/dirent.h` but it is not there. The same is available in `dirent.h` version of Linux.

I have read somewhere that `dirfd()` is not available in Solaris 9 and 10.

So, is there any equivalent workaround of this function in Solaris 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This late BSD function was standardized in 2008 while Solaris 9 was released in 2001 and Solaris 10 in 2005. That's the reason why it isn't available with these versions.

`dirfd` is available with the current version, Solaris 11.

For older ones, reimplementing `dirfd` seems to be obvious, given the fact the file descriptor is already in the passed structure, here `dir->d_fd` or `dir->dd_fd` depending on whether `__XOPEN_OR_POSIX` is defined or not.

Comment: Running a very little code fails with error: `test.c:13: error: structure has no member named fd`. Is this is the only possible solution?

Comment: Thanks @jiliagre. `dir->dd_fd` compiled without any error in Solaris 10. :)